# Cannot find symbol IOUtils

Tags: java

Basically I am trying to take information from a text file and turn it into a string. The code I have is:

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("filename.txt");
try 
{
  String everything = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
} 
finally 
{
  inputStream.close();
}
```

the error message I get is -->

```
java:53: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class IOUtils
location: class CheckSystem
```

I assumed this was because of my imports, but I have io and util and even text imported (just as below)

```
import java.util.*;

import java.text.*;

import java.io.*;
```

Why can't I access the IOUtils class and its methods? If that cannot be answered, an alternative but very simple means of reading a text file into a string would be fine.

Comment: IOUtils is part of Apache IO Commons, not part of the standard JDK. You can get it here: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/. Entire first page of Google results for "IOUtils" explicitly mentions Apache Commons... [sigh]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to read a text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/best-way-to-read-a-text-file)

Comment: Down-vote : lack of research;

Comment: hey sorry i actually did look all this up but im kind of new to programming so i honestly am not sure how to work with apache commons.

Comment: IOUtils is org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils, which you don't have an import for, and probably don't have on your classpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need anything outside of standard JDK to read from a text file easily and efficiently. For example you can do so like this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
try {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = br.readLine();

    while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
        line = br.readLine();
    }
    String everything = sb.toString();
} catch(IOException e) {
  }
  finally {
    br.close();
}
```

taken from: [Reading a plain text file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/best-way-to-read-a-text-file)

The `everything` String contains the contents of the `file.txt`, which must be located in the same directory as where the java class file is being run from.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I tried this from the other question as well and I kept getting the error message --> unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown.Do you know whats wrong here?

Comment: Probably because of the missing catch statement. I've added it in there. This shouldn't give you that problem anymore.